# Spring Cloud Gateway unable to find microservices (404 not found)

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

I am creating a simple Hotel Review System. For me all the microservices work correctly individually.But when I try to access them using API Gateway none of them work for me.

Below are the registerd services in the Eureka Server-
[image]

ApiGateway pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pranaysahu.gateway</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiGateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApiGateway</name>
    <description>This project is an implementation of api gateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

API Gateway applications.yml-

```
server:
  port: 8084

spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY

cloud:
  gateway:
    routes:
      - id: USER-SERVICE
        uri: lb://USER-SERVICE/
        predicates:
          - Path=/users/**

      - id: HOTEL-SERVICE
        uri: lb://HOTEL-SERVICE/
        predicates:
          - Path=/hotels/**

      - id: RATING-SERVICE
        uri: lb://RATING-SERVICE/
        predicates:
          - Path=/ratings/**

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Below is the error I am getting while testing-
[image]

Comment: I am not sure but I think you should define cloud config under "spring". Like spring->cloud-> gateway. Currently "cloud" is a root config

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get through. Can you please elaborate how to define it under spring.

Comment: I post a response as an example for you

Answer (score 0):

try this way. Note the indentation of "cloud"

```
spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
   gateway:
    routes:
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this properties inside your `application.yml`

Check if that helps

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lowerCaseServiceId: true
```